# List of dataframes to one DF; Extract date column from each DF in list, pass all values to single DF w/ columns 1985-2017)

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of 169 dataframes (*assetcount_dfs*) corresponding to squares on a geographical grid that each contain a bundle of assets. I would like to fill a separate dataframe counting the number of assets that begin on each date, per square, for years 1985-2017.

Here's how this list of dataframes is structured:

```
 Square1_DF (3 rows/assets)   | x | y | dates char[1989, N/A, 1991]
 ...
 Square169_DF (1 row/asset)   | x | y | dates char[2002]
```

I want to convert this to one dataframe counting these dates, in '*dateDF*':

```
            | 1989 | 1990 | ... | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 
 Square 1      0      1            3      2      0      
 ...
 Square 169    0      0            0      1      3
```

Here's a toy sample of my data. Within each of the data frames in `assetcount_dfs`, the 'val' column represents the dates I want to populate *dateDF* with:

```
  sdf1 <- data.frame(a = c("1","4","5","1"), x = c("sdf","asf","asdf","sdf"), val = c("2014","2012","#N/A", "2001"))
  sdf2 <- data.frame(a = c("1","4"), x = c("sdf","asdf"), val = c("#N/A","2011"))
  sdf3 <- data.frame(a = c("1","4","5","1","1"), x = c("sdf","asf","asdf","sdf","sdf"), val = c("2010","2015","2000","2002", "2003"))

  assetcount_dfs <- list(sdf1 = sdf1,sdf2 = sdf2,sdf3 = sdf3)

  date_range <- 1985:2017
  dateDF <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(date_range),nrow = 3))     # actual length is 169 rows, only using 3 for this example
  colnames(dateDF) <- paste0('X',1985:2017) # name columns 'X'DATE
  rownames(dateDF) <- names(assetcount_dfs)
  dateDF[] <- 0          # filled with zeroes
```

---

## Current attempt

Within each dataframe's 'val' column, I want to check if any of the date values were in the range 1985-2017, and if so, add them to dateDF's X--- date column.

I tried using 'purr' (like lapply) to operate on each DF but I'm struggling to understand where to go from here.

```
invisible(map(listx, function(df) {

for (i in df$val){
    if (as.integer(i) %in% 1985:2017){
    datesDF_colName <- paste0('X',i)
    dateDF[substitute(df), datesDF_colName] <- dateDF[[datesDF_colName]] + 1 
      # Attempt to set dateDF value at [grid-square DF's name / row, Column based on Year ]
    } 

}}))

# Output:    
# Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, substitute(df), datesDF_colName, value = 
# c(1,  : 
#  anyNA() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
# Called from: `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, substitute(df), datesDF_colName, 
# value = c(1, 
# 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
# 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 

# Note my sample code for 'listx' for some reason generates DFs with factors, although I am currently dealing with character arrays.
```

Comment: What determines which ROW the counts should go into in `dateDF`? Obviously, the counts go into the columns corresponding to appropriate year, but how do you know which row to put a particular count into? Also, what is `assetcount_dfs`?

Comment: There's a unique id for every grid-square in `assetcount_dfs` :  `"75923" "75924" "76565"` etc. So I gave `dateDF` the same row names, these same squares' unique ids. `(rownames(dateDF) <- names(assetcount_dfs)`

Comment: And what determines which row a count of occurrences of a particular year should go into?

Comment: Each dataframe within the list has IDs, the list's names. So all the values I extract from the dataframe's 'dates' column (here `val`) should go into the row in `dateDF` with that same ID. Every time I encounter a value between 1985 and 2017 in one of the dataframes, I want increment the corresponding column (say X2000 in `dateDF`)  and the row (defined by the initial list ID) by 1. That's why I made `dateDF` rownames equal to the IDs for the dataframes in the list

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "each dataframe within the list has IDs." There's no column labeled ID in any data frame, nor is there anything in `dateDF` that looks like "sdf1" or any values shared with the `a` or `x` columns in the smaller data frames. Maybe there are also 169 smaller data frames and each one corresponds to a row?

Comment: I have a list of length 169, and every element of this list is a dataframe. This list's names, i.e. names(assetcount_dfs) are numeric: 75923, 75924, etc. The dataframes are of different sizes, but they all contain some number of rows with corresponding integers representing dates. I could edit `dateDF` so it has a distinct column with the list's names, but I made them the row names instead. At the start I was trying to describe a simpler version of the structure/data, since these dataframes have 79 variable columns in reality. `val`, the date, is what I operate on. Should I delete the intro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `tidyverse()` to handle this. Instead of trying to edit `dateDF` in a loop, count how often a year appears together with a dataframe ID, then reshape the data into the format that you're looking for.

```
library(tidyverse)

assets2  <- assetcount_dfs %>% 
  # combine all the small data frames into a single big df
  bind_rows(.id = 'rowdf') %>% 
  # toss out the N/A values so they don't get counted
  filter(val != "#N/A")


simpleDateDF <- assets2 %>% 
  # count each year and what data frame it's from
  count(rowdf, val) %>% 
  # spread the years out into columns, using 0 as the default
  spread(val, n, fill = 0)
```